# Java - symbol not found (constructor)

Tags: java, constructor

So I'm writing some code that reads from a file:

`array[k] = Salesperson(infile.nextInt(), infile.nextInt(), myName);`

I wrote a constructor for Salesperson that looks somewhat likes this:

`public Salesperson(int cheese, int butter, String name)`

When I try to compile (first Salesperson, then the actual program), I get this:

`program.java:39: cannot find symbol`

`symbol  : method Salesperson(int,int,java.lang.String)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing the new keyword. e.g.

```
array[k] = new Salesperson(infile.nextInt(), infile.nextInt(), myName);
```

This is resulting in the compiler attempting to find a method called Salesperson that returns a type of Salesperson, which would be invalid anyway.

Comment: wow. I don't even know how both I and the person sitting next to me missed that @_@

Comment: A good IDE, like IntelliJ, would have found it faster than both of you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *new* keyword.
You should do it:

```
array[k] = new Salesperson(infile.nextInt(), infile.nextInt(), myName);
```

You can't assign without the new keyword because it's not a method where you can return a value.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you have declared an `array` of `Salesperson` objects and you want to put data into it from a file. What you are missing is the `new` keyword. Using `new` keyword creates a new object of the class and calls the `constuctor` in the process. You may use the follwing code:

```
array[k] = new Salesperson(infile.nextInt(), infile.nextInt(), myName);
```